# dynamic add ports to ansible docker_container

Tags: docker, ansible

I want to deploy multiple (same) containers, one with 2 exposed ports, one with 1 exposed port.

How do i tell ansible to do sometimes 1 port, somtimes multiple?
Is there a loop for "ports:"?

`localhost.yml:`

```yaml
services:
  - { "name": "item1", "image": "some_container_image:1", "count": "2", "ports": "12345,12346" }
  - { "name": "item2", "image": "some_container_image:1", "count": "1", "ports": "12347" }
```

ansible role:

```yaml
---
- name: Start services 
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    image: "{{ item.image }}"
    state: started
    ports:
      - "{{ item.ports }}"
    env:
      item1: "{{ item.count }}"
  with_items: "{{ services }}"
  when: services is defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ports` (alias for `published_ports`) option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html#parameter-published_ports) expects a list of ports or port mappings to expose/map.

Simply modify your variable

```yaml
services:
  - { "name": "item1", "image": "some_container_image:1", "count": "2", "ports": ["12345","12346"] }
  - { "name": "item2", "image": "some_container_image:1", "count": "1", "ports": ["12347"] }
```

Then pass that port list as is to the option in your loop:

```yaml
- name: Start services 
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    image: "{{ item.image }}"
    state: started
    ports: "{{ item.ports }}"
    env:
      item1: "{{ item.count }}"
  with_items: "{{ services }}"
  when: services is defined
```

*Note that since `service` is defined in a yaml file, you can make this more legible for everyone*

```yaml
services:
  - name: item1
    image: some_container_image:1
    count: 2
    ports:
      - 12345
      - 12346
  - name: item2
    image: some_container_image:1
    count: 1
    ports:
      - 12347
```

Comment: So close but didn't see it. This works perfectly. Thank you!